# How to ensure the right parameters is passed to a function call declared in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node, but I love it already. Only issue is, the asynchronous functionality is killing me.

I am using the google package to get my websites' rankings in google as so:

```
for (var j=0;j<keywords.length;j++) {
    var keyword = keywords[j];

    google(keyword, function(err, next, links) {

    console.log('Searching for keyword "' + keyword + '" in google.' + google.tld + ' ('+ google.lang +')');
      if (err) console.error(err);

      for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {

        var rank = i+1;

        console.log(keyword + ' #'+ rank + ' - ' + links[i].link + ' | ' + links[i].title);
        //link.href is an alias for link.link
        //console.log(links[i].description + "\n");
      }
      console.log('\n');
    });

}
```

My problem is that it the console log shows the same keyword for all websites, although I have defined three in my keywords array.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate problem here is that the `j` and `keyword` variables go on changing before the callbacks are called.

A simple solution is to protect this variable in a closure :

```
for (var j=0; j<keywords.length; j++) {
    (function(j){
        var keyword = keywords[j];
        ...
    })(j);
}
```

When you're just working with a simple array, then you can also use a closure through [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) :

```
keywords.forEach(function(keyword, j){
     ...
});
```

To deal with this kind of asynchronous problems, you should now dive in promises which help structure your code in a clearer (and less indented) way. [An introduction](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#what-are-promises-and-why-should-i-use-them).

Comment: you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) as an alternative

Comment: This works, but not for the stated reason, since `j` is never used inside the closure. It's `keyword` that needs to be wrapped inside a nested function scope.

Comment: @MarceloCantos In this case I find it clearer and much more maintainable to protect the loop variable. It's a design choice.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto, I will try this as I improve my code, seems like a more logical solution. Thank you.

Comment: @dystroy: Fine, but your explanation is still incorrect. The fact that `j` keeps changing has no bearing on the problem.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Of course it's keyword which is directly used (in the current code) and protecting it rather than j is enough but it doesn't matter (especially when you think about maintainability). Isn't that clear to you from my answer and comments ?

Comment: @dystroy: I'm not challenging your use of `j` as the function parameter; I don't dispute that your answer works. I'm pointing out that your analysis of the problem is wrong.